# Feature set of Fuse7 standalone w/ spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, jbossfuse

RedHat recently announced the Tech Preview of Fuse 7 both [on RH blog](https://middlewareblog.redhat.com/2018/02/27/announcing-red-hat-fuse-7-0-technical-preview-3/) and [on dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/announcing-fuse-7-tech-preview-3-release).
I am interested to on-premise deployment options, such as Fuse Standalone with Spring Boot for microservices.

Is there a list of the feature set for *Fuse Standalone w/ Spring Boot*?

I guess the set of features may vary depending on deployment flavor, so without a clear list of features I cannot figure out how this solution can be compared to - say - Camel routes on Spring Boot apps (possibly on docker/kubernetes).

Answer (score 0):

You can find components from which the Fuse product is made of here: https://access.redhat.com/articles/348423

Supported Spring Boot components are here: https://access.redhat.com/articles/3442361

You can also check Release notes for more details about supported/deprecated features https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.2/html/release_notes/